# Windows 7 does not show up after installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, multi-boot

Lets get straight to the problem. In the past I had Windows 7 but decided to install Windows 8 2 days ago. I created two partitions, one for Windows 8 to install on and one for my current Windows 7.

The problem is that now I've installed Windows 8 I don't seem to be able to dual-boot into Windows 7 anymore, even though I can venture into the partition through Windows 8 and explore all my files and settings of Windows 7.

I went to my MsConfig file (system configuration) and it doesn't seem to recognize two OSs on the computer either but only Windows 8.

Here is a screenshot highlighting the problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3hXo.jpg]

Comment: What methods did you use to obtain and install Windows 8?  Also, you say "I don't seem to be able to dual-boot into windows7 anymore" does that mean it did allow you to dual boot previously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). Install it on your Windows 8 and use the program to create an entry to your Windows 7.

It saved me on a customer with three operating systems in same scenario.